# Cweb: why are my chunk names not inserted with a newline?

Tags: web

I am using cweb from TeX Live as installed with macports, and I am using the LaTeX document class `cweb`.

When I insert a named chunk in my code, as such

```
\documentclass{cweb}

\begin{document}

@ Hello, world.

@<print ...@>=
printf( "Hello, world!\n" );
@

@c

int main( int __unused argc, char __unused *argv[] )
{
  @<print hello world@>

  return 0;
}
@

\end{document}
```

the newline after the chunk name `print hello world` and before `return 0;` is missing.

That is, my pdf is rendered something like

```
<print hello world>return 0;
```

which makes using cweb unusable for my purpose.

Is this a bug in the cweb document class or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable  document that shows the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I've expanded the example to be complete document which demonstrates the problem; at least for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@/` to add a manual line break in the `cweave` output:

```
{
  @<print hello world@>@/
  return 0;
}
```

produces

[image]